# what is the difference between static memeber variable in a class and global variable in C++?

Tags: c++

what is the difference between  static member variable in a class and global variable in C++?

I can access static member variable in a class anywhere in the program through class name(Classname::static variable) so while creating variable how to decide a variable to be static member variable in a class and global variable?

Comment: If it belongs to the class, it goes in the class.

Comment: If it is in the class you can add accesse specifiers public/private/protected to it. Normally you would make it private member to limit access to the variable so that it can only be accessed via the appropriate methods and thus control how the variable can be accessed.

Comment: You should also note that global mutable state is considered bad practice. As you are tightly coupling function (that use the global) to the variable.

Comment: you almost always want to avoid using global variable

Comment: One major benifit of static members is that you can access them from templated parameters. Not something that can be achieved with globals. This allows more generic code to be developed.
See here:
https://onlinegdb.com/r1_WxpUzr

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is the scope.

A static member variable is in the scope of a class and if you want to access it, you have to use the class scope qualification for the name. Like className::variableName. This prevents namespace pollutions. So, It cannot be mixed up with other variables.

A global variable is in the global scope and can be accessed from everywhere (if we have an external declaration or an inline definition): If we are in an inner scope, we can use the :: operator to select the scope.

There are also namespaces. If you define a variabale in a namespace, outside of a class or function, then it belongs to the namespace. To access it, you need to use the fully qualified name: ::namespaceName::variableName. For nested namespaces, you need to add more ::

See example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string variable{"global scope\n"};

namespace test{

    std::string variable{"namespace scope\n"};

    struct TestStruct {
        std::string variable{"class scope\n"};

        void function()
        {
            std::string variable{"function scope\n"};

            std::cout << variable << '\n' << this->variable << '\n' << ::test::variable << '\n' << ::variable << '\n';
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    test::TestStruct t;
    t.function();
    return 0;
}
```

But caveat. You need to know that, if you define a static class member, then it is common for all instances of the class. Because in reality it is a globale variable, just defined in the scope of the class.